# how to estimate the overhead of for loop using rdtsc in c programming

Tags: c, linux

I want to calculate the overhead of the parameters of a fucntion with increasing the parameters over a range of 0 to 7 . How to estimate the hardware overhead and software overhead .

Comment: `gettimeofday` works quite well on any POSIX system.  The `rdtsc` instruction only exists on x86 architectures, and doesn't work the same on all of them, so I recommend avoiding it.

Comment: @BenVoigt `clock_gettime` is now replacing `gettimeofday`.  I'm not sure when but, the man page says it will be removed in the future.

Comment: @tijko: There are platforms with `gettimeofday()` that do not have `clock_gettime()` yet — Mac OS X (10.11.4) is one such.  At the moment, `gettimeofday()` is more portable than `clock_gettime()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't really well posed. However, the most reliable way to execute the `rdtsc` instruction is to just call it with inline assembly, which is fully supported by all C compilers. Any timing function prescribed by a C standard will vary by implementation.  Intel has a really good white paper on the best way to implement `rdtsc` stuff [here](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf).  The major concern is out-of-order execution, which may be out of the scope of your question.

The best implementation I've found is in [this repo](https://github.com/fwyzard/chrono/), which I've adapted for my own use. This basic set of macros, assuming you have a compatible processor, will give you ~32 clock ticks of overhead on each call (you'll need to do testing for your own processor):

```
#include <cpuid.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/*** Low level interface ***/

/* there may be some unnecessary clobbering here*/
#define _setClockStart(HIs,LOs) {                                           \
asm volatile ("CPUID \n\t"                                                  \
              "RDTSC \n\t"                                                  \
              "mov %%edx, %0 \n\t"                                          \
              "mov %%eax, %1 \n\t":                                         \
              "=r" (HIs), "=r" (LOs)::                                      \
              "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");                              \
}

#define _setClockEnd(HIe,LOe) {                                             \
asm volatile ("RDTSCP \n\t"                                                 \
              "mov %%edx, %0 \n\t"                                          \
              "mov %%eax, %1 \n \t"                                         \
              "CPUID \n \t": "=r" (HIe), "=r" (LOe)::                       \
              "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");                              \
} 
#define _setClockBit(HIs,LOs,s,HIe,LOe,e) {                                 \
  s=LOs | ((uint64_t)HIs << 32);                                            \
  e=LOe | ((uint64_t)HIe << 32);                                            \
}
```

---

```
/*** High level interface ***/

typedef struct {
  volatile uint32_t hiStart;
  volatile uint32_t loStart;
  volatile uint32_t hiEnd;
  volatile uint32_t loEnd;
  volatile uint64_t tStart;
  volatile uint64_t tEnd;

  /*tend-tstart*/
  uint64_t tDur;
} timer_st;

#define startTimer(ts)                                                      \
{                                                                           \
  _setClockStart(ts.hiStart,ts.loStart);                                    \
} 


#define endTimer(ts)                                                        \
{                                                                           \
  _setClockEnd(ts.hiEnd,ts.loEnd);                                          \
  _setClockBit(ts.hiStart,ts.loStart,ts.tStart,                             \
      ts.hiEnd,ts.loEnd,ts.tEnd);                                           \
  ts.tDur=ts.tEnd-ts.tStart;                                                \
}                                                                             

#define lapTimer(ts)                                                        \
{                                                                           \
  ts.hiStart=ts.hiEnd;                                                      \
  ts.loStart=ts.loEnd;                                                      \
}
```

---

Then call it with something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "macros.h" /* Macros for calling rdtsc above */

#define SAMPLE_SIZE 100000

int main()
{
  timer_st ts; 
  register double mean=0;
  register double variance=0;
  int i;

  /* "Warmup" */
  for(i=1;i<SAMPLE_SIZE;i++)
  {
    startTimer(ts);
    endTimer(ts);
  }

  /* Data collection */
  for(i=1;i<SAMPLE_SIZE;i++)
  {
    startTimer(ts);
    endTimer(ts);
    mean+=ts.tDur;
  }

  mean/=SAMPLE_SIZE; 

  fprintf(stdout,"SampleSize: %d\nMeanOverhead: %f\n", SAMPLE_SIZE,mean);


  return 0;
}
```

On my Broadwell chip I got this output

```
SampleSize: 100000
MeanOverhead: 28.946490
```

A clock resolution of 29 clock tics is pretty good. Any library function that people typical use (like `gettimeofday`) will not have clock-level accuracy and an overhead ~200-300.

I'm not sure what you mean by "hardware overhead" vs "software overhead" but for the implementation above there are no function calls to do the timing nor intermediate code between `rdtsc` calls. So I suppose the software overhead would be zero.

Comment: `rdtsc` is inherently chip-specific and limited to (some) Intel CPUs.  Compilers do generally support `asm`, but the notations used vary — it is not, however, mandated by the C standard (for example, `asm` is not a keyword in standard C — ISO/IEC 9899:2011).  The standard C (or POSIX) timing functions are more reliably available across platforms and CPU types and will behave reliably — albeit (much) more slowly than assembler accessing the `rdtsc` instruction directly.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is `disassembly`, on Linux you can take help from `objdump`. `objdump` will help you to see how codes are generated. If you are not doing anything with those passed parameters, then it's just the difference of taking parameters from the stack and keep them on a register. Since these `mov` operations will costs few cpu cycles or so, therefore, it will be hard to came up with timing information but easier in terms of CPU cycles.