# Measuring cycles per byte for an algorithm

Tags: c++, c, gcc, benchmarking, simd

I have implemented a bit sliced implementation of the PRIMATEs cipher found here http://primates.ae/ in C. I have made it using SIMD programming, so I use the AVX2 instruction set in my code.

Im currently trying to accurately measure how effective my implementation is, but I do not really trust the current numbers, I am getting. With my current numbers, I get around 200 cycles per byte, which seem waaay over what over ciphers get.

Currently, my code looks like this

```
#typedef u64 unsigned long long

u64 start, finish;
u64 samples[1000000];
data = calloc(4000, sizeof(unsigned char));

//Performance test on a single core, as that is the standard when computing cycles/byte.
SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), 0x00000008);

//Find CPU clock speed
start = _rdtsc();
sleep(1000);
finish = _rdtsc();
cpu_frequency = finish-start;

//Take a lot of samples and use median of these.
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
   start = _rdtsc();
   encrypt(data);
   decrypt(data);
   finish = _rdtsc();
   samples[i] = finish - start;
}
qsort(samples);
u64 median = samples[500000];
double cycles_per_byte = 1 / (4000.00 / median);
```

I believe I am performing the calculations right, so I'm wondering...

- Is it wrong to use _rdtsc() for measuring cycles per byte?
- Could the reason be that I don't measure clock cycle spent exclusively on my code, but on the system as a whole? (I have no idea, if I can see how much is spent exclusive on my code in that case)
- Could the fact that I run it on Windows instead of e.g. linux do a huge difference?

I have tried compiling the code with both GCC and MSVC, which did no difference (GCC was about 1% faster with /O2 or /O3; cannot remember which). I'm running the tests exclusively on one core with Intel Turboboost and hyperthreading turned off.

My complete source-code is here: 
https://github.com/opolo/Bitsliced-AEAD/tree/master/Primates/APE120_Bitsliced
My test-suite is in Ref.c, while the bit sliced permutation is in Primate.c ... The code is not superclean right now, my bad. That's why I tried to give an example before and not just completely c/p my code.

Comment: It's [very easy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twchhe95.aspx) to find out what `_rdtsc` measures.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I did not doubt what _rdtsc measured. If I read the cpu_frequency variable, I could see that its value matched my CPU clockspeed, so it had to be the cycle-count. The fact that my cycle/byte count is really large though compared to other ciphers had me wonder, however, if it was wrong to use it. If it could give problems in multi-core environments, or if it was because I do not measure CPU cycles exclusively spent on my code (in case others do that.. I havent been able to find other cycle/byte code-measurements done with Windows API calls (such as _rdtsc()).

Comment: It's easy to do a quick sanity check - process a large-ish chunk of data with your cipher - large enough that it takes of the order of say 10 seconds to process. Then measure the "wall clock" time and divide by the no of bytes in your data. That should then give you a number that you can rely on as being in the right ball park - if it's very different from your `_rdtsc` measured value then you know you're doing something wrong (and *vice versa*).

Comment: Oh, now I get what you mean. You know that you're not measuring just the cycles of your own process, but wondering if that's the reason for the large numbers (right?). Sorry for the confusion. (And I would say that it is indeed the reason, but I don't know enough about Windows to answer.)

Comment: Calling `rdtsc` around a `sleep()` is not a sane way of finding clockspeed in a multiprocessor machine. `sleep()` probably causes the program to be scheduled out by the OS, and you don't know whether it will be scheduled back to the same processor (or processor core).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it wrong to use _rdtsc() for measuring cycles per byte?

No that's the correct way to do it. I prefer using inline assembly for `rdtsc` instructions to guarantee inlining. This is an implementation dependent function, so you don't really know what's going on. In particular you don't know if it's correctly preventing out-of-order execution. See [here for an inline asm solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961657/how-to-estimate-the-overhead-of-for-loop-using-rdtsc-in-c-programming/36963439#36963439). I have no idea what x86 intrinsics do.

> Could the reason be that I don't measure clock cycle spent exclusively on my code, but on the system as a whole?

Yes, there is some overhead for function calls. Usually there is an O(100) clock tick overhead on modern platforms. Shouldn't really matter if your dataset is large enough.

> Could the fact that I run it on Windows instead of e.g. linux do a huge difference?

Nah

---

So you're not getting the performance you want out of an algorithm? This all depends on how your implementation, so I wouldn't blame your timing functions off the bat.  There are many intricacies to perfecting an algorithm implementation.  If you've explicitly vectorized stuff with inline asm or intrinsics, be aware that a poor, or overly abstracted, implementation can perform worse than compared with standard C and an optimized compiler.  A good approach is to first write a C implementation of the algorithm as a benchmark and validation, then begin optimizing by hand.

Where are the encrypt/decrypt functions?

Comment: Very late answer - sorry. Was quite stressed those months. Long story short, your answer really ended up helping me, so it deserves a thanks: Thanks!! I needed it for my thesis, which I ended up getting an A for. One could say that it was partly thanks to the answer. I ended up using _rdtsc() and just make my dataset large enough as you suggest + do the same operation multiple times to make the small variances in speed neglible. It worked out well!